# C# MVC5 Upgrade broke Javascript loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Just upgraded a very old project from MVC 4 to 5 and now after the upgrade the Razor Partial views which were working fine no longer work.

By this I mean that in the partial views there is a Script file that is called at the bottom:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/simAvail.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And this was loading the JS and in that file some JQuery added CSS etc as needed to the elements on the page.  However after the upgrade this JS file is no longer loaded and I use this method on many pages in the project so wondered if anyone knows the reason why.

The data in the Partial view is loaded and displayed but all the styling and reading/posting of the changes via Ajax is no longer there as this is what the JS file adds to the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I Managed to fix this it turns out that when the upgrade to MVC5 happened part of the process as detailed on the MS instructions was to re-install all the Nuget's.  This part actually installed the latest versions of all the JS packages like JQuery/Knockout etc without me noticing.

This then caused there to be two versions of everything being loaded and thus caused the issue.  SO I deleted the old version of the JS packages and back running.